# Fill TabView from Pages' titles of corresponding SwipeView

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

Straitforward approach to create a multiple separate visible pages with easy navigation is to use `SwipeView` and `TabBar` together:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Page {
    id: page

    header: TabBar {
        id: tabBar

        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex

        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page1")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page2")
        }
    }

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView

        width: page.width
        height: page.height

        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page {
            width: swipeView.width
            height: swipeView.height

            title: qsTr("Page1")

            Pane {
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
        Page {
            width: swipeView.width
            height: swipeView.height

            title: qsTr("Page2")

            Pane {
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

There is `title` property in the `Page` component. It is not visible in the above case, but it is proper place to store the tab title on my mind. Can I generate (say, using `Repeater`) a contents of `TabBar` using some properties of `SwipeView` pages (namely `.title`) to fill `TabButton.text`?

I looked through documentation, but can't find a property of `SwipeView`, which allows me to get access to its pages by means of indices (e.g. `pages[index]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Qt Quick* is great! I found the answer really quickly:

```
Repeater {
    model: swipeView.count
    TabButton {
        text: swipeView.contentChildren[index].title
    }
}
```

or even simplier

```
Repeater {
    model: swipeView.contentChildren
    TabButton {
        text: modelData.title
    }
}
```